# what will happen if i will use addition operater between two object

Tags: javascript, object

I am begineer in javascript i want to what will happen if add two object using addition operator.

```js
var obj = { name: "mango" }
var obj2 = { name: "mango" }
var obj3 = obj + obj2
console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: why dont you try it..

Comment: `"[object Object][object Object]"`

Comment: @Kevin.a - Trying it gives the practical answer for these particular two objects, but doesn't provide any insight.

Comment: thanks that is right response and i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [addition operator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus) goes through a series of steps to figure out what to do depending on its operands.

Primarily, it will try to convert its operands to primitives, and then deal with the result. When an object is converted to a primitive, it will end up being a string, number, boolean, etc. depending on the object's implementation of [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and/or [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf). If it ends up with two strings, it concatenates them. If not, it converts the primitives to numbers and adds them mathematically.

A simple object (such as the ones in your code) ends up converting to the string `"[object Object]"`. So your result is that string concatenated to itself: `"[object Object][object Object]"`:

```js
var obj = {name:"mango"};
var obj2 = {name:"mango"};
var result=obj+obj2; // It's not an object, so I called it `result`
console.log(result);
```

Some objects convert to numbers or other primitives instead because of their implementation of `toString` and/or `valueOf`. As I said above, if the object converts to a primitive other than string or number, the addition operator converts the primitive to a number. For instance:

```js
const a = {
  value: true,
  valueOf() {
    return this.value;
  }
};
const b = {
  value: 41,
  valueOf() {
    return this.value;
  }
};
const result = a + b;
console.log(result); // 42
```

In that example, `a` converts to the primitive `true` (a boolean) and `b` converts to the number `41`. Since those aren't both strings, the addition operator converts them to numbers (`41` is already a number, `true` gets converted to `1`) and adds them together, getting `42`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing console.log(obj3) will log the result. As you can see it returns both objects in the following format : `[object Object][object Object]`. Notice this is not a new object, these objects returned are references to the old objects.

Comment: *"As you can see it returns both objects in the following format : [object Object][object Object]"* Not objects, primitive strings. *"Notice this is not a new object, these objects returned are refferences to the old objects."* No, they aren't references to anything (in fact, there's no "they", just an "it"). The primitive string is not a reference to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here the variable `obj` & `obj2` contains JSON object

```
var obj = {name:"mango"}
var obj2={name:"mango"}
var obj3=obj+obj2
```

With the reference of above code the output is,

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Actually the `+` operator actually concatenate the two or more variables.

```
var obj = "mango"
var obj2 = "mango"
var obj3 = obj + obj2
```

Output is,

```
mangomango
```